# Cannot insert data to database

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have a form to get user input developed by using JSP and a servlet and two java classes to fetch data and insert them to the database. I have developed database using mysql and it is running on tomcat server.

data from form are being passed by post method to the servlet and stores them in a vector.

Here is the code of servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String profession = request.getParameter("name");
    String features = request.getParameter("address");


    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();

    v.addElement(name);
    v.addElement(address);


    Enumeration vEnum = v.elements();

    j=SqlInsert.insertValues(vEnum);

    if (j==0){
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet SubmitUser</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Error</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    else{
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet SubmitUser</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Successfully Submmited</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    }
```

Here is the java class (SqlInsert) which fetch elements from vector and set to sql:

```
public class SqlInsert{

static int i=0;
Connection c=null;
static PreparedStatement statement = null;

public static int insertValues(Enumeration<String> params) {

      String sql = "INSERT INTO test (name, address
            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        Connection c = DbConnection.connectDB();
        System.out.println("connected " + c);
        statement = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        System.out.println("connected ");

        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        int k = 1;
        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
            String param = params.nextElement();
            statement.setString(k++, param);
        }  



        i = statement.executeUpdate();
        System.out.print(i);

        c.commit();


         } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("e " + ex.toString());
        }

     return i;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
    Enumeration vEnum = v.elements();
    SqlInsert.insertValues(vEnum);       


}
    }
```

Here is the java class which establish database connection

```
public class DbConnection {

private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/online_feedback";
private static Connection con;



public static Connection connectDB(){    
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
        System.out.println("Conn obj :::" + con);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DbConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return con;  
}


public static void main (String []args){

    DbConnection db = new DbConnection();
    Connection s = db.connectDB();
}
```

My problem is that whenever I submit the form, it seems that executeUpdate() returns 0. In server log, nothing is shown

Please help me to get through it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code won't even compile. At least missed a double quote

Comment: Your SQL must be incorrect. How many columns are you inserting?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: It is about 13 columns, for the time being I showed here only two.

Comment: @Raptor: What I get is "Error" which is coded to be shown when j equals to 0 in the servlet

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Provide complete SQL and what is the output when you execute the SQL via commandline?